# C++ Template for generic data types and STL containers

Tags: c++, templates, stl, containers

Is there a way to create a template function such that it accepts arguments of generic data types such as int and float along with arguments of STL containers such as vector and array.

For example, something like this:

```
template <some template expression X>
T doSomething()
{
    //do Something
    return T;
}
```

Then I call it like:

```
int a = doSomething<int>();
float b = doSomething<float>();
vector<int> c = doSomething<int, std::vector>(); //OR
vector<int> c = doSomething<std::vector<int>>(); //Either this or above
```

Is this possible? Can you have default template parameters? Overloading the same function twice, first one with one template, second one with a template template parameter, and passing

```
int a = doSomething<int>();
vector<int> c = doSomething<int, std::vector>();
```

works! I find a solution which tells how to pass a template template parameter. But is overloading like this the only solution?

Comment: `doSomething<std::vector<int>>()` is likely what you want. It should work without trouble.

Comment: Have you read about [variadic templates and parameter packs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack)?

Comment: `template <typename T> T doSomething() { return T{}; }` would seem to meet your requirements, as long as you accept `doSomething<std::vector<int>>()` call syntax.

Comment: I think return T{} might be a good suggestion. Because the problem was, returning int and float is easy. But returning a vector is different, because I need to pack in data using push_back or using initializer list and then return it. I forgot about using initializer list, which seems a clever way of doing it. I will give it a try and report my results here!